# How to return HTTP BadResponse message in the View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, web-applications, http-post

I am having issues returning the `BadRequest` message from my Web API to my View. The API method can either return the object, a simple `BadRequest` or one with the message *"Could not match"*.

The problem is that I don't know what and how to return when the API method returns a `BadRequest`. As it is right now, the Web Aplication controller only returns `View()`. I eventually changed it but I receive an error like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(GtlTitle gtlTitle)
{
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = GlobalVariables_Title.client.PostAsJsonAsync("", gtlTitle).Result;
        TempData["Success"] = "Added Successfully!";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "naughty");
    }
}
```

> The name HttpStatusCodeResult does not exist in current context

Below is my **WEB API TitleController.cs**

```
        [Route("api/title")]
    [HttpPost()]
    public IActionResult InsertTitle([FromBody] GtlTitle gtlTitle)
    {
        // if (_titleChecker.CheckTitle(gtlTitle.ISBN) is false)
        //{
        string pattern = "[0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*";
        Match m = Regex.Match(gtlTitle.ISBN, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            if (_titleChecker.CheckTitle(gtlTitle.ISBN) is false)
            {
                try
                {
                    return Ok(_gtlTitleRepository.InsertTitle(gtlTitle));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    return Ok(_volumesDBContext.InsertVolume_FromTitle(gtlTitle, gtlTitle.ISBN));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
        }
        else
            return BadRequest("Could not match");
        // }
        // else
        //return Ok(_volumesDBContext.InsertVolume_FromTitle(gtlTitle, gtlTitle.ISBN));
    }
```

Therefore, what should I return in my `HttpPost` method? Even though `HttpStatusCodeResult`, I still feel that I am missing out with the other code as well.

Comment: You will need to check the HttpResponseMessage for the status code. I don't believe that `PostAsJsonAsync` will not throw an exception on a BadRequest response.

Comment: Alright, I got it. But now my question is, how can I return what I just posted (if it worked) and how can I return a `BadRequest` when it didn;t work? As you said, with `PostAsJsonAsync` I can't retrieve a BadRequest - then how can I do both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something in the line of this:

*Psedo code*

```
if (response.Status == HttpStatusCode.Ok) 
    return Redirect(...); 
else 
    return BadRequest(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```